# Correct Use of conditional II & conditilan III

Tags: conditional-constructions

"If Alexander Graham Bell, the inventor of the telephone, had been around today he’d have been quite bemused by how we’ve dis-invented his invention."

In above sentence conditional  has been used. It's referring to a hypothetical situation in the Past.

This I read in context where present situation is discribe. I mean present usages of phone other than calling etc.
Refer below LInk.

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/jugglebandhi/phonely-enough-a-device-meant-for-people-to-talk-to-each-other-is-used-for-anything-but-that-f0-9f-98-9c/

According to my knowledge writer should have used conditional II type. It refers to a hypothetical situation in the present or the future (subjunctive).

So the sentence should be like this

"If Alexander Graham Bell, the inventor of the telephone, were around today he would quite bemused by how we’ve disinvented his invention."

Comment: You are right (with the addition of _be_ : _would be quite bemused_).

Comment: You are entirely correct; the sentence is in the wrong tense.

Comment: Your correct, as already commented, however where is the question your asking? I only see a statement

Comment: @Brad you're*, please.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're correct. The correct use of conditional, for this phrase, would be (like you wrote):

> *"If Alexander Graham Bell, the inventor of the telephone, **were** around today, he **would be** quite bemused by how we’ve dis-invented his invention."*

One easy way to validating the first phrase wrong is looking at *(1) had been around* next to *(2) today*. (1) refers to past, while (2) refers to present. It doesn't add up.

Comment: You should have checked your grammar before you posted the answer. Do you see what's wrong about "One easy way to validating the first phrase wrong is looking at ..."?